# Search a value in the column value that stores comma separated values

Tags: oracle

Suppose I have table XYZ with a column Weekend_Days which stores the value, SUNDAY,SATURDAY and I have another table ABC with a date, ACT_DATE which can be any date. Now I have to check if the day on this date is a weekend or not.

I tried using:

```
select  ACT_DATE
,       case 
            when UPPER(TO_CHAR(ACT_DATE,'DAY')) IN (SELECT Weekend_Days from XYZ) 
               then 1 
            else 0 
        end as Weekend_Flag 
from ABC
```

But it is not working, its just returning 0 for all dates.

Tried storing the value of Weekend_Days as ('SUNDAY','SATURDAY') but it didn't work.

Sample Data:

**Table XYZ:**

```
WEEKEND_DAYS
---------------
SUNDAY,SATURDAY
```

**Table ABC:**

```
ACT_DATE
---------
02-Feb-16
06-Feb-16
```

**Current Result:**

```
ACT_DATE  WEEKEND_FLAG
--------- ------------
02-Feb-16            0
06-Feb-16            0
```

**Expected Result:**

```
ACT_DATE  WEEKEND_FLAG
--------- ------------
02-Feb-16            0
06-Feb-16            1
```

Comment: Please tag your DBMS properly, I don't think you use both `mysql` and `oracle`. Also, could you post some sample data?

Comment: Post the create and insert statements. And show your desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_String(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_result       SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST();
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start );
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 );
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_result;
END;
/

CREATE TABLE xyz ( weekend_days ) AS
SELECT 'SATURDAY,SUNDAY' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE abc ( act_date ) AS
SELECT DATE '2016-02-02' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT DATE '2016-02-06' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**

```
SELECT act_date,
       CASE WHEN w.Weekend_day IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS weekend_flag
FROM  abc a
      LEFT OUTER JOIN
      ( SELECT t.column_value AS weekend_day
        FROM   xyz x,
               TABLE( split_String( x.weekend_days ) ) t
      ) w
      ON TRIM( TO_CHAR( a.ACT_DATE, 'DAY' ) ) = w.Weekend_day;
```

**Output**:

```
ACT_DATE  WEEKEND_FLAG
--------- ------------
06-FEB-16            1 
02-FEB-16            0
```

**Alternate Query**:

```
SELECT act_date,
       CASE
         WHEN INSTR( x.weekend_days, TRIM( TO_CHAR( act_date, 'DAY' ) ) ) > 0
         THEN 1
         ELSE 0
         END AS weekend_flag
FROM   abc a
       CROSS JOIN
       xyz x;
```

This will give the same output and will work for names of days but will not work for a general case as you might get a false positive match to a sub-string.

Answer (score -1):

**UPDATE**

As I didn't understood OPs question on the first way, here is the new statement which should work now!

```
SELECT
ACT_DATE,
CASE
WHEN UPPER(DATENAME(DW, ACT_DATE)) IN ( SELECT LEFT(Weekend_Days, CHARINDEX(',', Weekend_days + ',') - 1) AS Sat FROM @XYZ
                                        UNION ALL
                                        SELECT STUFF(Weekend_Days, 1, CHARINDEX(',', Weekend_Days + ','), '') AS Sun FROM @XYZ)
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS Weekend_flag
FROM @ABC
```

**OLD:**

```
SELECT
ACT_DATE,
CASE
WHEN UPPER(DATENAME(DW, ACT_DATE)) IN (SELECT Weekend_Days FROM XYZ)
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS Weekend_flag
FROM ABC
```

You can get the day of the week with the method "DATENAME" with the interval "Week - dw" given. Referencing to: http://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/datename.php

Hope this helps!

**EDIT:**

OP said the IN function isn't working. Well I tried it with dummy datas and for me it IS working. Here is my dummy statement:

```
DECLARE @XYZ Table(Weekend_Days varchar(255))
DECLARE @ABC Table(ACT_DATE datetime)

INSERT INTO @XYZ VALUES('SAMSTAG')
INSERT INTO @XYZ VALUES('SONNTAG')

INSERT INTO @ABC VALUES('02-Feb-16')
INSERT INTO @ABC VALUES('03-Feb-16')
INSERT INTO @ABC VALUES('04-Feb-16')
INSERT INTO @ABC VALUES('05-Feb-16')
INSERT INTO @ABC VALUES('06-Feb-16')
INSERT INTO @ABC VALUES('07-Feb-16')
INSERT INTO @ABC VALUES('08-Feb-16')
INSERT INTO @ABC VALUES('09-Feb-16')
INSERT INTO @ABC VALUES('10-Feb-16')
INSERT INTO @ABC VALUES('11-Feb-16')
INSERT INTO @ABC VALUES('12-Feb-16')
INSERT INTO @ABC VALUES('13-Feb-16')
INSERT INTO @ABC VALUES('14-Feb-16')
INSERT INTO @ABC VALUES('15-Feb-16')
INSERT INTO @ABC VALUES('16-Feb-16')

SELECT
ACT_DATE,
CASE
    WHEN UPPER(DATENAME(DW, ACT_DATE)) IN (SELECT Weekend_Days FROM @XYZ)
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS Weekend_flag
FROM @ABC
```

My result is following:

```
ACT_DATE    Weekend_flag
2016-02-23 11:37:48.810 0
2016-02-02 00:00:00.000 0
2016-02-03 00:00:00.000 0
2016-02-04 00:00:00.000 0
2016-02-05 00:00:00.000 0
2016-02-06 00:00:00.000 1
2016-02-07 00:00:00.000 1
2016-02-08 00:00:00.000 0
2016-02-09 00:00:00.000 0
2016-02-10 00:00:00.000 0
2016-02-11 00:00:00.000 0
2016-02-12 00:00:00.000 0
2016-02-13 00:00:00.000 1
2016-02-14 00:00:00.000 1
2016-02-15 00:00:00.000 0
2016-02-16 00:00:00.000 0
```

Comment: I am getting the day of the week from the mentioned method, its the IN function that is not working

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the problem, the value of both the weekend days is stored in a single cell, so try using : INSERT INTO @XYZ VALUES('SUNDAY,SATURDAY') and try getting the expected result

Comment: My bad! Look at new statement soon.

Comment: This does not appear to be an Oracle answer.

Comment: As far as I remember this thread was tagged with SQL also...
I didn't see that he removed the other tag! And for SQL, this is the answer.