# How to sort multiline text in Oracle db?

Tags: oracle, sorting, multiline

I need to create a script that will sort (and update) all values in column A for all records in table B if the text in the field is in more than one line.

Any ideas how to do it? I'm a begginer in Oracle world so any help is appreciated.

```
Table B
id   column A
1    aaa
2    bb \n aa\n dd \n cc
3    bb \n aa
```

*(\n is new line)

I need it to be

```
  Table B
    id   column A
    1    aaa
    2    aa \n bb\n cc \n dd
    3    aa \n bb
```

Comment: Can you please post the structure of your tables, with an example of data and desired result?

Comment: Question is updated with example.

Comment: In any programming language this is trivial. What are your constraints?

Comment: It sounds like you are saying not that you want to sort the result set but that you want to update the data in the table so that the different segments of the string are in alphabetical order.  Is that correct?  If so, that indicates a serious problem with your data model.  It sounds like you should be storing the text in multiple rows in a child table to begin with.

Comment: Yes I need to update the values. And yes, that is new request that causing the problem but I cant change it now. I'm sorting new values from app but I have old values already in the db. Thats why I need this sorting script.

Comment: @Raffaele I implemented this already in Java, for new values, but for existing, I want to execute it directly on database in order to avoid huge data load on production.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE Table_B ( id, column_A ) AS
SELECT 1, 'aaa' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'bb ' || CHR(10) || ' aa' || CHR(10) || ' dd ' || CHR(10) || ' cc' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'bb ' || CHR(10) || ' aa' FROM DUAL;
```

Also uses my [SPLIT_STRING function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35577315/1509264):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_String(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_result       SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST := SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST();
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start );
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 );
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_result;
END;
/
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT id,
       LISTAGG( COLUMN_VALUE, CHR(10) )
         WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY TRIM(COLUMN_VALUE) )
         AS sorted_column_a
FROM   Table_B B,
       TABLE( split_String( b.column_a, CHR(10) ) ) s
GROUP BY ID
```

**Output**

```
        ID SORTED_COLUMN_A       
---------- ----------------
         1 aaa              
         2  aa              
           bb               
            cc              
            dd              

         3  aa              
           bb
```

**Update**

```
UPDATE TABLE_B b
SET column_a = ( SELECT LISTAGG( COLUMN_VALUE, CHR(10) )
                          WITHIN GROUP ( ORDER BY TRIM(COLUMN_VALUE) )
                 FROM   TABLE( split_String( b.column_a, CHR(10) ) ) );
```

Comment: This looks perfect. It should be it. Let me apply it and I will accept the answer...

Comment: @DjordjeIvanovic Just added a `TRIM()` to the `ORDER BY` clause as it was including the leading whitespace in the sort which was throwing it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this, which delimits individual value of text using '\n' and sort it. And later merge it in ascending order that you mentioned.

```
with mydata(id,text)
as
(
  select 1, replace('aaa','\n',chr(10)) from dual
  union all
  select 2, replace('bb \n aa\n dd \n cc','\n',chr(10)) from dual
  union all
  select 3, replace('bb \n aa','\n',chr(10)) from dual
)
SELECT ID,REPLACE(LISTAGG(text_splitted,chr(10)) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY trim(text_splitted)),CHR(10),'\n')
FROM
(
SELECT  t1.id,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(t1.text, '([^'||chr(10)||'])+', 1, t2.COLUMN_VALUE) text_splitted
FROM mydata t1 CROSS JOIN
            TABLE
            (
                CAST
                (
                    MULTISET
                    (
                        SELECT LEVEL
                        FROM DUAL 
                        CONNECT BY LEVEL <= REGEXP_COUNT(t1.text, '([^'||chr(10)||'])+')
                    )
                    AS SYS.odciNumberList
                )
            ) t2
)
GROUP BY ID;
```

`'\n'` - new line character will be saved as `CHR(10)` (`ASCII` value) in database. I used the same for conversion. Later used \n for display purpose.