# Oracle pipelined table function and insert results into an Oracle table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-insert

I'm using an Oracle pipelined table function and based on the records returned, I would like to insert each row of data into an Oracle table, that has the exact same column count, i.e.:

I have written a `split` function that has a `return type pipelined` which all works fine.

```
SELECT column_value as val
FROM   TABLE(split(',AA,BB,CC,,,FF,GG,,,HH,'))
```

which returns me 11 rows of data under the columns alias of `val`

```
val
----
NULL
AA
BB
CC,
NULL
NULL
FF
GG
NULL
NULL
HH
```

Now I also have a `msg_log` table that has the following definition:

```
CREATE TABLE msg_log
(
    C001    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C002    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C003    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C004    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C005    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C006    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C007    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C008    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C009    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C010    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    C011    VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE)
);
```

Using the values return from my pipelined `split` function, how can I access each individual 11 records and insert them into my `msg_log` table.

Basically would like to take each row and insert it into my table.

Comment: **msg_log** has 11 columns and your **split** function returns only one (11 rows but **1** column). `insert into msg_log` (without the explicit list of columns) expect **11** columns, thus the error.

Comment: @NickKrasnov ok, so is there a means of achieving what I am after based on my question, i.e. split out each row and insert into columns?

Comment: Are you looking to pivoting the result **split()** function produces?

Comment: Your list has 12 values (not 11) as there is a trailing comma so there will be `NULL` for the 12th value.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Oracle Setup**:

Pipelined version of [this split function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35577315/1509264):

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN SYS.ODCIVARCHAR2LIST PIPELINED
AS
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      PIPE ROW( SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start ) );
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      PIPE ROW ( SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 ) );
    END IF;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

**Insert**:

Just add a row number and pivot:

```sql
INSERT INTO msg_log ( C001, C002, C003, C004, C005, C006, C007, C008, C009, C010, C011 )
SELECT *
FROM   (
  SELECT ROWNUM AS RN,
         COLUMN_VALUE As value
  FROM   TABLE( SPLIT( ',AA,BB,CC,,,FF,GG,,,HH,' ) )
)
PIVOT( MAX( value ) FOR rn IN ( 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 ) )
```

**Output**:

```sql
SELECT * FROM msg_log;
```

> ```
> C001 | C002 | C003 | C004 | C005 | C006 | C007 | C008 | C009 | C010 | C011
> :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :--- | :---
> null | AA   | BB   | CC   | null | null | FF   | GG   | null | null | HH
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=f220c71a5bcd792aacbced5927deefff)*