# Oracle cursor for assignation

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have the below 2 tables:

t1

| VK | AY | AN | R |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VK1 |  | A1, A2 | 1 |
| VK2 |  |  | 2 |
| VK3 |  | A1, A2, A3, A4 | 3 |
| VK4 |  | A2 | 4 |
| VK5 |  |  | 5 |
| VK6 |  |  | 6 |
| VK7 | A3 |  | 7 |
| VK8 |  |  | 8 |
| VK9 |  |  | 9 |
| VK10 |  |  | 10 |
| VK11 |  |  | 11 |
| VK12 |  |  | 12 |
| VK13 | A3 |  | 13 |
| VK14 |  |  | 14 |
| VK15 | A3 |  | 15 |
| VK16 |  |  | 16 |
| VK17 |  |  | 17 |
| VK18 |  |  | 18 |
| VK19 |  |  | 19 |
| VK20 |  |  | 20 |

t2

| A | C |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | 4 |
| A2 | 10 |
| A3 | 2 |
| A4 | 10 |

I would like to create a **plsql cursor** to add a column AF with the logic below:

1. The objective is to assign the different As in t2 to the rows in t1. It's column R which determines the order in which, if possible, they should be assigned.
2. If column **AY** is populated, then that 'A' should be assigned to AF if C in t2 is still >0 (after the previous assignations).
3. If column **AN** is populated, then none of the 'A's listed there can be assigned to that row.
4. The assignation of 'A's must be done proportionally to their C in t2.

The below would be one example of desired output (AF could be assigned in any other order though).

| VK | AY | AN | R | AF | EXPLANATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| VK1 |  | A1, A2 | 1 | A4 | A3 and A4 available: A4 chosen. |
| VK2 |  |  | 2 | A2 | All available: A2 chosen. |
| VK3 |  | A1, A2, A3, A4 | 3 | null | None are available: cannot pick any. |
| VK4 |  | A2 | 4 | A4 | All but A2 available: A4 chosen |
| VK5 |  |  | 5 | A2 | All available: A2 chosen. |
| VK6 |  |  | 6 | A1 | All available: A1 chosen. |
| VK7 | A3 |  | 7 | A3 | A3 must be assigned: A3 chosen |
| VK8 |  |  | 8 | A2 | All available: A2 chosen. |
| VK9 |  |  | 9 | A4 | All available: A4 chosen. |
| VK10 |  |  | 10 | A4 | All available: A4 chosen. |
| VK11 |  |  | 11 | A2 | All available: A2 chosen. |
| VK12 |  |  | 12 | A1 | All available: A1 chosen. |
| VK13 | A3 |  | 13 | A3 | A3 must be assigned: A3 chosen |
| VK14 |  |  | 14 | A2 | All available: A2 chosen. |
| VK15 | A3 |  | 15 | null | A3 must be assigned but A3 already exhausted: cannot be assigned |
| VK16 |  |  | 16 | A4 | All available: A4 chosen. |
| VK17 |  |  | 17 | A4 | All available: A4 chosen. |
| VK18 |  |  | 18 | A2 | All available: A2 chosen. |
| VK19 |  |  | 19 | A2 | All available: A2 chosen. |
| VK20 |  |  | 20 | A1 | All available: A1 chosen. |

Please find below the sample query for the tables:

```
with t1 (vk, ay, an, r) as(
    select 'VK1', null, 'A1, A2', 1 from dual union all
    select 'VK2', null, null, 2 from dual union all
    select 'VK3', null, 'A1, A2, A3, A4', 3 from dual union all
    select 'VK4', null, 'A2', 4 from dual union all
    select 'VK5', null, null, 5 from dual union all
    select 'VK6', null, null, 6 from dual union all
    select 'VK7', 'A3', null, 7 from dual union all
    select 'VK8', null, null, 8 from dual union all
    select 'VK9', null, null, 9 from dual union all
    select 'VK10', null, null, 10 from dual union all
    select 'VK11', null, null, 11 from dual union all
    select 'VK12', null, null, 12 from dual union all
    select 'VK13', 'A3', null, 13 from dual union all
    select 'VK14', null, null, 14 from dual union all
    select 'VK15', 'A3', null, 15 from dual union all
    select 'VK16', null, null, 16 from dual union all
    select 'VK17', null, null, 17 from dual union all
    select 'VK18', null, null, 18 from dual union all
    select 'VK19', null, null, 19 from dual union all
    select 'VK20', null, null, 20 from dual),
t2 (a, c) as (
    select 'A1', 4 from dual union all
    select 'A2', 10 from dual union all
    select 'A3', 2 from dual union all
    select 'A4', 10 from dual)
select * from t1;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up the data types and helper functions:

```sql
CREATE TYPE string_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(2);
/

CREATE TYPE int_list IS TABLE OF INT;
/

CREATE TYPE t1_data AS OBJECT(
  vk VARCHAR2(4),
  ay VARCHAR2(2),
  an VARCHAR2(14),
  r  INT,
  c  VARCHAR2(2)
);
/

CREATE TYPE t1_table IS TABLE OF t1_data;
/

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_String(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN string_list DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_result       string_list := string_list();
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35577315/1509264
  -- License: CC BY-SA 4.0
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start );
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 );
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_result;
END;
/
```

Then you can use the function:

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION pick_values RETURN t1_table PIPELINED
IS
  TYPE t2_type IS TABLE OF t2%ROWTYPE;
  
  t2_data t2_type;
BEGIN
  -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/67398434/1509264
  -- License: CC BY-SA 4.0
  SELECT *
  BULK COLLECT INTO t2_data
  FROM  t2;
  
  FOR cur IN ( SELECT * FROM t1 ORDER BY r )
  LOOP
    DECLARE
      a_freqs  INT_LIST := INT_LIST();
      cum_freq INT := 0;
      taken    STRING_LIST := SPLIT_STRING( cur.an, ', ' );
      idx      INT;
      c        T2.A%TYPE;
    BEGIN
      a_freqs.EXTEND(t2_data.COUNT);
      FOR i IN 1 .. t2_data.COUNT LOOP
        IF ( t2_data(i).a = cur.ay AND t2_data(i).c > 0 )
           OR ( cur.ay IS NULL AND t2_data(i).a NOT MEMBER OF taken AND t2_data(i).c > 0 )
        THEN
          a_freqs(i) := cum_freq + t2_data(i).c;
          cum_freq := cum_freq + t2_data(i).c;
        ELSE
          a_freqs(i) := cum_freq;
        END IF;
      END LOOP;
      IF cum_freq > 0 THEN
        idx := FLOOR(DBMS_RANDOM.VALUE(0, cum_freq));
        FOR i IN 1 .. t2_data.COUNT LOOP
          IF idx < a_freqs(i) THEN
            c := t2_data(i).a;
            t2_data(i).c := t2_data(i).c - 1;
            EXIT;
          END IF;
        END LOOP;
      END IF;
      PIPE ROW(
        t1_data(
          cur.vk, cur.ay, cur.an, cur.r, c
        )
      );
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

Which, for your sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE t1 (vk, ay, an, r) as
    select 'VK1', null, 'A1, A2', 1 from dual union all
    select 'VK2', null, null, 2 from dual union all
    select 'VK3', null, 'A1, A2, A3, A4', 3 from dual union all
    select 'VK4', null, 'A2', 4 from dual union all
    select 'VK5', null, null, 5 from dual union all
    select 'VK6', null, null, 6 from dual union all
    select 'VK7', 'A3', null, 7 from dual union all
    select 'VK8', null, null, 8 from dual union all
    select 'VK9', null, null, 9 from dual union all
    select 'VK10', null, null, 10 from dual union all
    select 'VK11', null, null, 11 from dual union all
    select 'VK12', null, null, 12 from dual union all
    select 'VK13', 'A3', null, 13 from dual union all
    select 'VK14', null, null, 14 from dual union all
    select 'VK15', 'A3', null, 15 from dual union all
    select 'VK16', null, null, 16 from dual union all
    select 'VK17', null, null, 17 from dual union all
    select 'VK18', null, null, 18 from dual union all
    select 'VK19', null, null, 19 from dual union all
    select 'VK20', null, null, 20 from dual;

CREATE TABLE t2 (a, c) as
    select 'A1', 4 from dual union all
    select 'A2', 10 from dual union all
    select 'A3', 2 from dual union all
    select 'A4', 10 from dual;
```

Then:

```sql
SELECT * FROM PICK_VALUES();
```

May output:

> | VK | AY | AN | R | C |
> | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
> | VK1 |  | A1, A2 | 1 | A4 |
> | VK2 |  |  | 2 | A2 |
> | VK3 |  | A1, A2, A3, A4 | 3 |  |
> | VK4 |  | A2 | 4 | A1 |
> | VK5 |  |  | 5 | A2 |
> | VK6 |  |  | 6 | A2 |
> | VK7 | A3 |  | 7 | A3 |
> | VK8 |  |  | 8 | A1 |
> | VK9 |  |  | 9 | A2 |
> | VK10 |  |  | 10 | A4 |
> | VK11 |  |  | 11 | A2 |
> | VK12 |  |  | 12 | A1 |
> | VK13 | A3 |  | 13 | A3 |
> | VK14 |  |  | 14 | A4 |
> | VK15 | A3 |  | 15 |  |
> | VK16 |  |  | 16 | A4 |
> | VK17 |  |  | 17 | A2 |
> | VK18 |  |  | 18 | A4 |
> | VK19 |  |  | 19 | A4 |
> | VK20 |  |  | 20 | A4 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=815fdd8f9decc3f859e527d678bd922f)*

Comment: It throws this error LINE/COL  ERROR
--------- -------------------------------------------------------------
3/1       PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CREATE" 
Errors: check compiler log

Comment: @jeiv No, it doesn't. Check the db<>fiddle linked in the answer.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I had to execute one by one.

Comment: Now it says there's some error ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 26 when executing SELECT * FROM PICK_VALUES(); I'm using Oracle 12c if that helps.

Comment: Try `SELECT * FROM TABLE( PICK_VALUES() );`

Comment: Working like a charm now! Let me understand the code and run some test against it and I will validate the answer :) Great effort!

Comment: Could you please introduce some comments on the first block mainly? I'm a little bit lost on what all those things do.

Comment: @jeiv `CREATE TYPE` creates a data type and you have: data type for a list (array) of strings; a data type for a list (array) of integers; an object data type with the columns you want to return; a data type for a list (array) of those objects; and a function to split a delimited string into a list of strings. The name of those each of those is, hopefully, self-explanatory as to what they represent.

Comment: What does this line do? a_freqs.extend(t2_data.count);

Comment: @jeiv https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#CJAIJHEI

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/232045/discussion-between-jeiv-and-mt0).