# Function cursor assignation

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a function -please find a MRE at the end of the question-, which assigns, by partition of pc and order by r, if 'ay' is not null, that 'ay', if an has any values, then those values cannot be picked. However, I'm struggling to understand how the below part works (namely how, if cur.ay is not null, then the assigned a is ay).
I would also need to enhance this function to include also logic for a column 'ao' which, if possible then assigned to that 'a', but, if cur.c<=0, try to assign it to any of the available 'a's.
Could someone clarify how the logic in the loop works so I can try to enhance the logic myself?

```
FOR i IN 1..t2_data.count LOOP IF ( t2_data(i).a = cur.ay AND t2_data(i).c > 0 ) OR ( cur.ay IS NULL AND t2_data(i).a
NOT MEMBER OF taken AND t2_data(i).c > 0 ) THEN
```

EDIT:

Please find below an example of output:

| PC | VK | AY | AO | AN | R | EXPLANATION |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | VK1 | null | A1 | A2, A3 | A1 | AO is suggesting A1, so, since A1 has capacity, it's assigned to A1 |
| 2 | VK1 | A1 | null | A2, A3 | A1 | AY is saying it should go only, if capacity, to A1, so, since A1 has capacity, it's assigned to A1 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |
| N | VK1 | null | A1 | A2, A3 | A4 | AO is suggesting A1,but, assuming the capacity for A1 is already exhausted and that A4 has capacity yet, it's assigned to A4 (A2 and A3 are forbidden) |

Please find below the function:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pick_values RETURN t1_prueba_table
    PIPELINED
IS
    TYPE t2_type IS
        TABLE OF t2%rowtype;
    t2_data   t2_type;
    v_pc      t1.pc%TYPE;
BEGIN
  -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/67398434/1509264
  -- License: CC BY-SA 4.0
    FOR cur IN (
        SELECT
            *
        FROM
            t1
        ORDER BY
            pc,
            r
    ) LOOP
        IF v_pc IS NULL OR v_pc <> cur.pc THEN
            v_pc := cur.pc;
            SELECT
                *
            BULK COLLECT
            INTO t2_data
            FROM
                t2
            WHERE
                pc = cur.pc;

        END IF;

        DECLARE
            a_freqs    int_list := int_list();
            cum_freq   INT := 0;
            taken      string_list := split_string(cur.an, ', ');
            idx        INT;
            c          t2.a%TYPE;
        BEGIN
            a_freqs.extend(t2_data.count);
            FOR i IN 1..t2_data.count LOOP IF ( t2_data(i).a = cur.ay AND t2_data(i).c > 0 ) OR ( cur.ay IS NULL AND t2_data(i).a
            NOT MEMBER OF taken AND t2_data(i).c > 0 ) THEN
                a_freqs(i) := cum_freq + t2_data(i).c;
                cum_freq := cum_freq + t2_data(i).c;
            ELSE
                a_freqs(i) := cum_freq;
            END IF;
            END LOOP;

            IF cum_freq > 0 THEN
                idx := floor(dbms_random.value(0, cum_freq));
                FOR i IN 1..t2_data.count LOOP IF idx < a_freqs(i) THEN
                    c := t2_data(i).a;
                    t2_data(i).c := t2_data(i).c - 1;
                    EXIT;
                END IF;
                END LOOP;

            END IF;

            PIPE ROW ( t1_prueba_data(cur.pc, cur.vk, cur.ay, cur.ao, cur.an, cur.r,
        c) );

        END;

    END LOOP;
END;
```

The tables and types for the MRE are below:

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (pc, vk, ay, ao, an, r) as
    select 1, 'VK1', null, null, 'A1, A2', 1 from dual union all
    select 1, 'VK2', null, null, null, 2 from dual union all
    select 1, 'VK3', null, null, 'A1, A2, A3, A4', 3 from dual union all
    select 1, 'VK4', null, null, 'A2', 4 from dual union all
    select 1, 'VK5', null, null, null, 5 from dual union all
    select 1, 'VK6', null, null, null, 6 from dual union all
    select 1, 'VK7', 'A3', null, null, 7 from dual union all
    select 1, 'VK8', null, null, null, 8 from dual union all
    select 1, 'VK9', null, null, null, 9 from dual union all
    select 1, 'VK10', null, null, null, 10 from dual union all
    select 1, 'VK11', null, null, null, 11 from dual union all
    select 1, 'VK12', null, null, null, 12 from dual union all
    select 1, 'VK13', 'A3', null, null, 13 from dual union all
    select 1, 'VK14', null, null, null, 14 from dual union all
    select 1, 'VK15', 'A3', null, null, 15 from dual union all
    select 1, 'VK16', null, null, null, 16 from dual union all
    select 1, 'VK17', null, null, null, 17 from dual union all
    select 1, 'VK18', null, null, null, 18 from dual union all
    select 1, 'VK19', null, 'A1', null, 19 from dual union all
    select 1, 'VK20', null, null, null, 20 from dual union all
    select 2, 'VK1', null, null, 'A1, A2', 1 from dual union all
    select 2, 'VK2', null, null, null, 2 from dual union all
    select 2, 'VK3', null, null, 'A1, A2, A3, A4', 3 from dual union all
    select 2, 'VK4', null, null, 'A2', 4 from dual union all
    select 2, 'VK5', null, null, null, 5 from dual union all
    select 2, 'VK6', null, null, null, 6 from dual union all
    select 2, 'VK7', 'A3', null, null, 7 from dual union all
    select 2, 'VK8', null, null, null, 8 from dual union all
    select 2, 'VK9', null, null, null, 9 from dual union all
    select 2, 'VK10', null, null, null, 10 from dual union all
    select 2, 'VK11', null, null, null, 11 from dual union all
    select 2, 'VK12', null, null, null, 12 from dual union all
    select 2, 'VK13', 'A3', null, null, 13 from dual union all
    select 2, 'VK14', null, null, null, 14 from dual union all
    select 2, 'VK15', 'A3', null, null, 15 from dual union all
    select 2, 'VK16', null, null, null, 16 from dual union all
    select 2, 'VK17', null, null, null, 17 from dual union all
    select 2, 'VK18', null, null, null, 18 from dual union all
    select 2, 'VK19', null, null, null, 19 from dual union all
    select 2, 'VK20', null, null, null, 20 from dual;

CREATE TABLE t2 (pc, a, c) as
    select 1, 'A1', 4 from dual union all
    select 1, 'A2', 10 from dual union all
    select 1, 'A3', 2 from dual union all
    select 1, 'A4', 10 from dual union all
    select 2, 'A1', 11 from dual union all
    select 2, 'A2', 1 from dual union all
    select 2, 'A3', 4 from dual union all
    select 2, 'A4', 6 from dual;


CREATE TYPE t1_prueba_data AS OBJECT (
    pc   INT,
    vk   VARCHAR2(4),
    ay   VARCHAR2(2),
    ao   VARCHAR2(2),
    an   VARCHAR2(14),
    r    INT,
    c    VARCHAR2(2)
);
CREATE TYPE t1_prueba_table IS TABLE OF t1_prueba_data;
```

Comment: Please [edit] the question with your expected output; your description of the problem is not clear what behaviour you expect for the `ao` column.

Comment: @MT0 please find my question edited.

Comment: @MT0 even a comment on how, if ay is not null is assigned if enough c, ay is assigned would be enough. I'll try to enhance the logic for 'ao' on my own.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION pick_values RETURN t1_prueba_table
    PIPELINED
IS
    TYPE t2_type IS
        TABLE OF t2%rowtype;
    t2_data   t2_type;
    v_pc      t1.pc%TYPE;
BEGIN
  -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/67516191/1509264
  -- License: CC BY-SA 4.0
  FOR cur IN (
    SELECT *
    FROM   t1
    ORDER BY pc, r
  ) LOOP
    IF v_pc IS NULL OR v_pc <> cur.pc THEN
      v_pc := cur.pc;
      SELECT *
      BULK COLLECT INTO t2_data
      FROM   t2
      WHERE  pc = cur.pc;
    END IF;

    DECLARE
      a_freqs    int_list := int_list();
      cum_freq   INT := 0;
      taken      string_list := split_string(cur.an, ', ');
      idx        INT;
      c          t2.a%TYPE;
      
    BEGIN
      a_freqs.extend(t2_data.count);
      FOR i IN 1..t2_data.count LOOP
        IF     t2_data(i).a = cur.ao
           AND t2_data(i).c > 0
        THEN
          -- If there is an "ao" value and it has capacity then assign it to "c"
          c := t2_data(i).a;
          -- Decrement the appropriate "t2_data" row to show it has been used.
          t2_data(i).c := t2_data(i).c - 1;
          -- Set the "cum_freq" to 0 so the loop where values are randomly assigned is skipped.
          cum_freq := 0;
          -- Exit the loop
          EXIT;
        ELSIF ( 
                t2_data(i).a = cur.ay
            AND t2_data(i).c > 0
          ) OR (
                cur.ay IS NULL
            AND t2_data(i).a NOT MEMBER OF taken
            AND t2_data(i).c > 0
          )
        THEN
          a_freqs(i) := cum_freq + t2_data(i).c;
          cum_freq := cum_freq + t2_data(i).c;
        ELSE
          a_freqs(i) := cum_freq;
        END IF;
      END LOOP;

      IF cum_freq > 0 THEN
        idx := floor(dbms_random.value(0, cum_freq));
        FOR i IN 1..t2_data.count LOOP
          IF idx < a_freqs(i) THEN
            c := t2_data(i).a;
            t2_data(i).c := t2_data(i).c - 1;
            EXIT;
          END IF;
        END LOOP;
      END IF;

      PIPE ROW (
        t1_prueba_data(cur.pc, cur.vk, cur.ay, cur.ao, cur.an, cur.r, c)
      );
    END;
  END LOOP;
END;
/
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bf51c4749382a338a52bab836e152a14)*

Comment: Thanks a lot! Could you please provide a brief explanation on how this logic works?       a_freqs.extend(t2_data.count);
      FOR i IN 1..t2_data.count LOOP
        IF     t2_data(i).a = cur.ao
           AND t2_data(i).c > 0
        THEN
          c := t2_data(i).a;
          t2_data(i).c := t2_data(i).c - 1;
          cum_freq := 0;
          EXIT;
        ELSIF ( 
                t2_data(i).a = cur.ay
            AND t2_data(i).c > 0
          ) OR (
                cur.ay IS NULL
            AND t2_data(i).a NOT MEMBER OF taken
            AND t2_data(i).c > 0
          )

Comment: Thanks! Ok, so, if ao has capacity, it will assign to it if c>0 and if not, it will try the existing method. How does it check that, if ay is not null, it is assigned to ay or not assigned?

Comment: In the `ELSIF` section.

Comment: But how does it say, if there's capacity for ay, then go for ay and decrement c. (Sorry, this is actually a question on the already existing code). I can see that there's an OR condition checked, but if the first one is met (the ay one), what would be the cummulative frequencies?

Comment: Is that not explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67421465/1509264)?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I just saw the bit of code.  It was cur.ay IS NULL in the OR condition which I was not realising was there.