# Function with table parameters Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the below function. I would like to make it parametrisable. I would want to give as input parameters table_t5 and dunnv3_t6. Would this be possible? I know how to define functions with strings, numbers... as parameters but I'm struggling to pass tables as input parameters.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dunnv3_ec_assign RETURN t5_table
    PIPELINED
IS
    TYPE t6_type IS
        TABLE OF dunnv3_t6%rowtype;
    t6_data   t6_type;
    v_cc      table_t5.campaign_code%TYPE;
BEGIN
  -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/67398434/1509264
  -- License: CC BY-SA 4.0
    FOR cur IN (
        logic which orders the input table for cursor processing
    ) LOOP
        IF v_cc IS NULL OR v_cc <> cur.cc THEN
            v_cc := cur.cc;
            SELECT
                *
            BULK COLLECT
            INTO t6_data
            FROM
                dunnv3_t6
            WHERE
                cc = cur.cc;

        END IF;

        DECLARE
            a_freqs    int_list := int_list();
            cum_freq   INT := 0;
            taken      string_list := split_string(cur.an, ', ');
            idx        INT;
            c          dunnv3_t6.a%TYPE;
        BEGIN
            a_freqs.extend(t6_data.count);
            FOR i IN 1..t6_data.count LOOP IF ( t6_data(i).a = cur.ay AND t6_data(i).c > 0 ) OR ( cur.ay IS NULL AND t6_data(i).a
            NOT MEMBER OF taken AND t6_data(i).c > 0 ) THEN
                a_freqs(i) := cum_freq + t6_data(i).c;
                cum_freq := cum_freq + t6_data(i).c;
            ELSE
                a_freqs(i) := cum_freq;
            END IF;
            END LOOP;

            IF cum_freq > 0 THEN
                idx := floor(dbms_random.value(0, cum_freq));
                FOR i IN 1..t6_data.count LOOP IF idx < a_freqs(i) THEN
                    c := t6_data(i).a;
                    t6_data(i).c := t6_data(i).c - 1;
                    EXIT;
                END IF;
                END LOOP;

            END IF;

            PIPE ROW ( t5_data(cur.vk, cur.ay, cur.an, cur.cc, cur.r,
        c) );

        END;

    END LOOP;
END;

CREATE TYPE t5_data AS OBJECT (
    vk   NVARCHAR2(12),
    ay   CHAR(10),
    an   VARCHAR2(4000),
    cc   VARCHAR2(5),
    r    NUMBER,
    c    CHAR(10)
);

CREATE TYPE t5_table IS
    TABLE OF t5_data;
```

Oracle version 12.1. Kindly let me know if additional info required.

EDIT, I would also need the 'logic which logic which orders the input table for cursor processing to be passed as a parameter.

Comment: What do you mean by "pass tables as input parameters"? Do you mean to pass a set of rows? Or do you mean to pass the name of the table and dynamically change the tables you are selecting from?

Comment: I mean pass the table names (and also, as per my last edit, the logic for ordering the first input table for the cursor). The function does not actually change the tables but generates an output table.

Comment: Mostly you don't. Passing table names would involve dynamic SQL and then you are defining a user-defined collection type based on `%ROWTYPE` of the passed table and you cannot easily do that; you would need to define most of your query dynamically. Just don't ... it would be simpler to create one function for each table.

Comment: In theory this **might** be possible. But for all practical purposes it **cannot be done**. Virtually the entire thing would need to be dynamic SQL.  Specifically everything that references dunnv3_t6,  table_t5, and everything derived form them.

Comment: @MT0  Ok, thanks both for the answer. I will create one function for each combination of tables, no big deal.