# Oracle PLSQL return value when calling function split_string

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have the below function

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION split_String(
  i_str    IN  VARCHAR2,
  i_delim  IN  VARCHAR2 DEFAULT ','
) RETURN string_list DETERMINISTIC
AS
  p_result       string_list := string_list();
  p_start        NUMBER(5) := 1;
  p_end          NUMBER(5);
  c_len CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_str );
  c_ld  CONSTANT NUMBER(5) := LENGTH( i_delim );
BEGIN
  -- https://stackoverflow.com/a/35577315/1509264
  -- License: CC BY-SA 4.0
  IF c_len > 0 THEN
    p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    WHILE p_end > 0 LOOP
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, p_end - p_start );
      p_start := p_end + c_ld;
      p_end := INSTR( i_str, i_delim, p_start );
    END LOOP;
    IF p_start <= c_len + 1 THEN
      p_result.EXTEND;
      p_result( p_result.COUNT ) := SUBSTR( i_str, p_start, c_len - p_start + 1 );
    END IF;
  END IF;
  RETURN p_result;
END;
...
```

However, if I try to call I like the below, I get the below value:

```
SELECT
    split_string('A1, A2', ', ')
FROM
    dual;
```

USER.STRING_LIST('A1', 'A2')

What type of value is the function returning?

Comment: You haven't shown us line 24 of your function, so we have no way of helping you, beyond saying that one of your local string variables (also not shown) is too small for what you are trying to put into it.

Comment: I'm really sorry, I was not passing one the function parameters in the call. I've amended the question.

Comment: The second argument has a default so you don't need it. Looking at the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35577315/266304) you've taken this from, you've replaced a built-in collection type with your own `string_list` type - so how is that defined?

Comment: @Alex Poole CREATE TYPE string_list IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(2);

Comment: I didn't realise you'd changed the question... so, you figured out that the original error was because the second value has a leading space - ` A2` - and was too long, unless you changed the default delimiter. Anyway...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're getting back an instance of the `string_list` collection. Some clients will display that, some won't.

If you want to get the individual elements you can use a [table collection expression](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SELECT.html#GUID-CFA006CA-6FF1-4972-821E-6996142A51C6__GUID-D92F6514-D6D4-48F2-8A43-FAF5FFEA53B4) to unnest the values:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    TABLE(split_string('A1, A2', ', '));
```

which will then give you:

```
COLUMN_VALUE
------------
A1
A2
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=bf83b6d7d3cb9e733cb997bc810a3f8a)

Comment: Perhaps worth mentioning also - in more recent versions (at least since 12.2), the use of the `table` operator is optional. That makes the query look even simpler - `select * from split_string(...)`.

Comment: @mathguy I have 12c, so mine throws this error ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended
00933. 00000 -  "SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: @jeiv - "12c" is a marketing name Oracle uses for all sub-versions of version 12 of its database product. From what you shared, I understand that your version is 12.1. And it confirms that the `table` operator is required up to version 12.1, and it was made optional starting with version 12.2. Speaking of versions: please run `select * from v$version` and make a note of your Oracle version - full number, perhaps something like 12.1.0.4.0, and include it in all your future questions, as it is very often relevant. Cheers!

Comment: Oracle Database 12c Enterprise Edition Release 12.1.0.2.0 - 64bit Production I'll make sure I include that in my future questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

"What type of value" is not ambiguous or hard to understand - that is (and must be) specified in the `return` clause of the function declaration. In your case, it is `string_list`.

The better question is, what data type is `string_list`. You already showed that in a comment: it is a user-defined type, which is a nested table of strings of length at most 2. It is defined in the schema `USER` (which is a really odd name for a user; it is probably defined in double-quotes, `"USER"`, as unquoted `USER` is a reserved keyword - but this has nothing to do with your question).